# Coreference: Is this a expected output of a coreference system?

Tags: anaphora

Consider the following piece of text:

'The father of Richard is a very nice guy. He was born in a poor family. Because of that, Richard learnt very good values. Richard is also a very nice guy. However, Richard's mother embarasses the family. She was born rich and she does not know the real value of the money. She did not have to be a hard worker to succeed in life."

How should a coreference system should work? Is this a good solution?

Cluster 1:

```
'The father of Richard' (first sentence) <-> 'He' (second sentence)
```

Cluster 2:

```
'Richard' (third sentence) <-> 'Richard' (forth sentence)
```

Cluster 3:

```
'Richard\'s mother' (fifth sentence) <-> She (sixth sentence) <-> she (sixth sentence) <-> She (seventh sentence)
```

Due to the ambiguity, we maybe could have (?):

Cluster 1:

```
'He' (second sentence) <-> 'Richard' (third sentence) <-> 'Richard' (forth sentence)
```

Cluster 2:

```
'Richard\'s mother' (fifth sentence) <-> She (sixth sentence) <-> she (sixth sentence) <-> She (seventh sentence)
```

However, as I understand, we can never have "the father of Richard" and "Richard" at the same cluster. Am I correct?

My doubt is about the mention "Richard". Although "Richard" is the same person in all sentences, the mentions are about different people (his father and his mother). How does coreference treat this?